# Fundamental theorem of calculus

Tags: calculus

I have been working on a calculus problem for a while now and I am just completely stumped. The question is asking to evaluate the $\int_{-10}^{10}8x^9+5x^5 dx$. How do I do about this problem?

Comment: Hint: Don't do a lot of work for nothing.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int^{10}_{-10}8x^9+5x^5dx\\
\implies\int^{10}_{-10}8x^9dx+\int^{10}_{-10}5x^5dx\\
\implies\left[8\frac{x^{10}}{10}\right]^{10}_{-10}+\left[5\frac{x^{6}}{6}\right]^{10}_{-10}$$